# does this operation dataframe.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK()) and dataframe.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK) are same?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

does this operation 
`dataframe.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK())` and `dataframe.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)` are same ? 
Trying to find the correct syntax please help

Comment: The second is correct (without parenthesis) - the first one doesn't even compile (at least not in Scala, with Spark 2.0.+)

Comment: Im using this in java. So When i ran with the first one didnt get any compilation issues

Answer (score 0):

In Java API, [`StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/storage/StorageLevel.html#MEMORY_AND_DISK()) is the only option, as it is a static method, and as such cannot be passed, only called.